# Incorrect query using BelongTo / HasMany Association in Sequalize ORM

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm getting a bad query using auto-generated function "addXXXs"

Models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
    return sequelize.define('Product', {
        internal_code:{type:types.STRING},
        name:{type:types.STRING},
        description:{type:types.STRING},
        unit:{type:types.STRING},
        precio:{type:types.DECIMAL},
        alicuota:{type:types.DECIMAL},
        stock:{type:types.INTEGER},
        service:{type:types.INTEGER}
    })
}

module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
    return sequelize.define('Imageproduct', {
        image:{type:types.STRING}
    })
}
```

Relations:

```
db.Imageproduct.belongsTo(db.Product);
db.Product.hasMany(db.Imageproduct);
```

Queries:

```
product = await db.Product.create(my_product);
images  = await db.Imageproduct.bulkCreate(my_images_list);
assoc   = await product.addImageproducts(images);
```

Generated queries:

```
1 - Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Products" ("internal_code","name","description","unit","precio","alicuota","stock","service","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('P007',' 
Guitarra electrica','Guitarra electrica','',32.1,0.21,5,0,'2019-04-01 21:30:17.498 +00:00','2019-04-01 21:30:17.498 +00:00') RETURNING *;                               

2 - Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Imageproducts" ("id","image","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'blabla.png','2019-04-01 21:30:17.591 +00:00','2019-04-01 21:30:
17.591 +00:00'),(DEFAULT,'blabla.jpg','2019-04-01 21:30:17.591 +00:00','2019-04-01 21:30:17.591 +00:00');                                                               

3 - Executing (default): UPDATE "Imageproducts" SET "ProductId"=3,"updatedAt"='2019-04-01 21:30:17.667 +00:00' WHERE "id" IN (NULL, NULL)
```

1 and 2 are correct, but I expect some valid ID into IN clause in query 3, not NULL, in fact, I expect the images' IDs inserted before into the IN clause in query 3;
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
images  = await db.Imageproduct.bulkCreate(my_images_list);
```

to

```
images  = await db.Imageproduct.bulkCreate(my_images_list, { returning:true });
```

This way, you get the new records' ID in the images objects. (postgresql only)